# How can I add an HTML jQuery table to display a database?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, sql-server-2005

I need to show a database in a table present in the ASP.NET. I got some suggestions, such as DataGridView slowing down our process. So I use jQuery table. But how do I display the data in jQuery table in an ASP.NET MVC webpage from an SQL Server database.

Comment: Are you also new to jQuery? There's two problems, one is to find a jQuery solution for the table, and one problem is to output the data from the server. I think you should figure out the jQuery solution first, then the rest will be easy.

Answer (score 1):

For a jQuery table, you could implement an action that JSON-encode your data. The jQuery table can then be configured to fetch the data through that source:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetJsonData()
{
    var data = /* Get your data here */;

    return Json(data);
}
```

Then you configure the data-table to fetch data from a remote source, like specified in the [documentation](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/ajax.html):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": 'http://www.yourdomain.com/yourController/GetJsonData',
        "sServerMethod": "POST"
    } );
});
```

**Not sure that this would improve your performance though.**